# How to read custom header entry of WebClient

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

Lets say I have

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Set("MyFlag", "12356");
```

How can read **"MyFlag"** later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `Headers` is read/write, so you can write:

```
string value = client.Headers["MyFlag"];
```

By the way, you can also use this to set the header:

```
client.Headers["MyFlag"] = "123456";
```

See [WebHeaderCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webheadercollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation.

Comment: If the specific header can have more than one value (eg. a Cookie), be sure to use the `WebHeaderCollection.Add()` method so that [previous values aren't overwritten](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d0bzeeb.aspx).